# QML mouseArea losing focus on releasing mouse button

Tags: qt, qml

In my program you have polygons on screen, and you can drag their sides, the verticies, or the whole polygons around. I want to show the user which will happen with the mouse in its current position. For that I need the onPositionChanged event handler of the mouseArea this is happening in.

The dragging works fine, the problem is that the mouseArea loses focus the moment the mouse is released on it, so I'm not able to call my onPositionChanged function when the user is not pressing a mouse button.

HoverEnabled is set to true in my mouseArea. It seems some other object keeps stealing focus, but I set preventStealing to true, set focus to true, and looked for the word "focus" in the whole project, and removed every line that would steal focus There are also no focusScopes in the project.
example code:

```
MouseArea
{
    hoverEnaled: true
    focus: true
    preventStealing: true
    ...
    onPositionChanged:
    {
        doStuff();
        //Works fine while mouse button is pressed. Doesn't get called when it's released 
    }
    Component.onCompleted: forceActiveFocus();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi there, please provide a [mcve] (i.e. code that reproduces your problem) to your question. It's difficult for some of us to draw a paragraph in our heads. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you TrebuchetMS. I tried reproducing the problem in a new project, but there the mouseArea worked even when dinamically created. It seems then, that dynamic creation has nothing to do with the bug. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Hi again Artur, thanks for editing your question. Right now, I... don't see how this reproduces your problem of the stolen focus. Is there a parent to the mouseArea that you anchor it to? (I can also do `console.debug(mouseX, mouseY)` in `onPositionChanged` with `hoverEnabled:true` and that would print output even when the mouse is released, solving the problem posed in the comment.) I can definitely say, it's may be a Minimal example. But make sure that it is [Complete and Verifiable as well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! While trying to replicate my problem, I ended up solving it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
Before getting to my polygon screen, there was a popup in the program, that was closed improperly (instead of `popup.close()`, `popup.visible = false; popup.destroy();` was used). Closing it the proper way solved my problem.